# keep associative array when decoding json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

for example I have the following array:-

```
$menu = array(
    "result"=>array(
        "food"=>array(
            "Nasi Padang",
            "Kentang Goreng",
            "Potato Wedges"
        ),
        "drink"=>array(
            "Bajigur",
            "AO",
            "Sabun"
        )
    )
);
```

using `json_encode` the above code become:-

```
{
    "result":{
        "food":[
            "Nasi Padang",
            "Kentang Goreng",
            "Potato Wedges"
        ],
        "drink":[
            "Bajigur",
            "AO",
            "Sabun"
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, `result` array become an object instead of stay in form of array, maybe this is because JavaScript doesn't have an associative array out of the box.

so, is there anyway to treat the `result` (after doing `json_decode`) as array without any casting like `(array)`?

EDIT:
response to Anant reply/comment, I tried the following code in my localhost

```
$test = new stdClass;
$test->count = 1337;
$test->page = 2;

$menu = array(
    "test"=>$test,
    "result"=>array(
        "food"=>array(
            "Nasi Padang",
            "Kentang Goreng",
            "Potato Wedges"
        ),
        "drink"=>array(
            "Bajigur",
            "AO",
            "Sabun"
        )
    )
);

$json = json_encode($menu);
echo print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1337
            [page] => 2
        )

    [result] => Array
        (
            [food] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Nasi Padang
                    [1] => Kentang Goreng
                    [2] => Potato Wedges
                )

            [drink] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bajigur
                    [1] => AO
                    [2] => Sabun
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: JSON must always be wrapped in `{ }`, you can't have a JSON object that's a list. You can have a list directly inside the JSON, but the outside must be `{ }`

Comment: @Anant: I see..but what if there is also real object (`stdClass`) inside the array? will the object also converted into associative array?

Comment: @DarielPratama  function with true parameter will convert it completely, not half-of it. So if you have requirement of both in your resultant array then do manually with some coding stuff

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see, result array become an object instead of stay in form of array, maybe this is because JavaScript doesn't have an associative array out of the box.

It's because in JSON, a plain object serves the same purpose as an associative array in PHP. The only difference is that it is not ordered.

JSON doesn't have an data structure with named properties that is also ordered. To achieve that you would need to use an array of objects such as:

```
[
    { "name" : "foo", "value" : 1 },
    { "name" : "bar", "value" : 2 }
]
```

> so, is there anyway to treat the result (after doing json_decode) as array without any casting like (array)?

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> assoc:  When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So set the second argument of `json_decode` to `true`.

Comment: Aren't JSON objects (member names) in document order? Or how is that _"in JSON, a plain object serves the same purpose as an associative array in PHP. **The only difference is that it is not ordered.**"_ to be understood? (Maybe I don't fully grasp "ordered" in this context)

Comment: “does not assign any significance to the ordering of name/value pairs” - https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf